# boolean algebra simplification to remove extra term

Tags: boolean-algebra

how do i simplify this equation using boolean algebra:

> AB + ¬AC + BC

to be equal to

> AB + ¬AC

the BC is unneeded, but how do i remove that term using boolean algebra?

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
AB+\lnot AC+BC&=AB+\lnot AC+(A+\lnot A)BC\\
&=AB+\lnot AC+ABC+\lnot ABC\\
&=(AB+ABC)+(\lnot AC+\lnot ACB)\\
&=AB+\lnot AC
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$
A + \lnot A = 1
$$

And:
$$
BC = 1 \cdot BC = (A + \lnot A)BC = ABC + \lnot ABC
$$

Plug into your expression to get:
\begin{align*}
AB + \lnot AC + BC &= AB + \lnot AC + (ABC + \lnot ABC) \\
&= (AB + ABC) + (\lnot AC + \lnot ABC) \\
&= \left(AB + (AB)C\right) + \left(\lnot AC + (\lnot AC)B\right) \\
&= AB + \lnot AC
\end{align*}